# ASP.NET AJAX Textbox to DataList/Grid

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, datagridview

I'm looking to create a free-type textbox which onkeyout "filters" a datagrid below.  The old way to do this was to write a webservice and call it on each press returning the results - I was hoping there was a more eloquent way of doing this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Documentation/Tutorials/Sites etc all welcomed.

Sorry for the very noob question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have luck in find an answer in this Stackoverflow question:

[Filtering a list as you type with jQuery.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772035/filtering-a-list-as-you-type-with-jquery/1772073#1772073)

Or possibly with this Stackoverflow question:

[vb.net dataTable/DataGridView search/sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752040/vb-net-datatable-datagridview-search-sort/1752089#1752089)

Hope this helps some.